# CSS Menubar no SubMenus

Tags: css, xhtml

I am a beginner in CSS and I would like to create a Menu with SubItems. 
I have found a model on the internet and I would like to customize it but it doesn't work. 
In the text you can find the XHTML and CSS File with just the Menu. 
The Menu is shown correct but I want that the subMenus like 'Team' is shown with the corresponding Item.

I have searched on the internet and customized the " #menu ul li:hover > ul { " several times but I can't see the error. I think the error must be in that function because I want to appear the menu when I move the mouse over the Menu.

Could you please tell me where the error is?

```css
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700);




p, ul, li, div, nav 
{ 

padding:0; margin:0; 
} 

body { 
font-family:Calibri; 
} 

#menu 
{ 
position: absolute; overflow: auto;  z-index:2; 
} 

.parent-menu { 
background-color: white; 
color:black;
min-width:200px;
 float:left;
 } 
 
#menu ul 
 { 
 list-style-type:none; 
 } 
 
#menu ul li a {
 
  padding:10px 15px; 
  display:block; 
  color:black; 
  text-decoration:none; }

#menu ul li a:hover {
 background-color:blue; 
 }


#menu ul li:hover > ul { 
left: 200px; -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in; -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in; -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in; transition: left 200ms ease-in; 
} 


#menu ul li > ul {
 position: absolute; background-color: #333; top: 0; left: -200px; min-width: 200px; z-index: -1; height: 100%; -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in; -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in; -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in; transition: left 200ms ease-in; } 
 
 #menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
  background-color:#2e2e2e;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
 <title>CSS Site</title>


    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>


<body>
 <header class="header">
  <h1>CSS Site</h1>
 </header>
 <nav id="menu">
  <ul class="parent-menu">
   <li><a  href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li>
    <a  href="#">About</a>
    <ul>
     <li> Team</li>
     <li> Philosophie</li>
     <li> Partner</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a  href="#">References</a></li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <ul>
     <li>Way</li>
     <li>Rooms</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your ul being child of li if you want it to stay like this you would need to do next manipulations.

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/JaVAaMunLFnT3TPGNQnY?p=preview
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700);




p, ul, li, div, nav 
{ 

padding:0; margin:0; 
} 

body { 
font-family:Calibri; 
} 

#menu 
{ 
position: absolute; overflow: auto;  z-index:2; 
} 

.parent-menu { 
background-color: white; 
color:black;
min-width:400px;
 float:left;
 } 
 
#menu ul 
 { 
 list-style-type:none;
 } 
#menu li {
  width:200px;
}
 
#menu ul li a {
 
  padding:10px 15px; 
  display:block; 
  color:black; 
  text-decoration:none; }

#menu ul li a:hover {
 background-color:blue; 
 }


#menu ul li:hover > ul { 
top: 0px; 
-webkit-transition: top 200ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: top 200ms ease-in; 
-ms-transition: top 200ms ease-in; 
transition: top 200ms ease-in; 
} 


#menu ul li > ul {
 position: absolute; 
 background-color: #333;
 top: -200px; 
 left: 200px;
 min-width: 200px; 
 z-index: 0; 
 height: 100%; 
 -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
 -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
 transition: left 200ms ease-in; 
  
} 
 
 #menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
  background-color:#2e2e2e;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <header class="header">
  <h1>CSS Site</h1>
 </header>
 <nav id="menu">
  <ul class="parent-menu">
   <li><a  href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li>
    <a  href="#">About</a>
    <ul>
     <li> Team</li>
     <li> Philosophie</li>
     <li> Partner</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a  href="#">References</a></li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <ul>
     <li>Way</li>
     <li>Rooms</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

  </body>

</html>
```

I changed animation from left to top, because it was causing problems with z-indexes, if it's necessary to be left, let me know and I'll try to help you out

Answer (score 0):

You were missing too many things.

**your HTML**

```
<header class="header">
  <h1>CSS Site</h1>
</header>
<nav id="menu">
  <ul class="parent-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <ul>
        <li> Team</li>
        <li> Philosophie</li>
        <li> Partner</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">References</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Way</li>
        <li>Rooms</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS code that I've created**

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.parent-menu li:hover a,
.parent-menu li ul li:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.parent-menu li ul {
  display: none;
}

.parent-menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 290px;
  top: 0px;
}

.parent-menu li {
  position: relative;
}
```

In it I've created a basic code which is you required to do so.

Try to understand code yourself and if you stuck somewhere then post your comment here.